# Fedora Container No 'find' Command Available

Tags: bash, find, containers, fedora, dnf

I've built a container with:

```
> cat Dockerfile
FROM fedora:latest

USER root

RUN dnf update -y && \
    dnf clean all && \
    dnf autoremove

> docker build -t dev .
> docker run -t -d <container_id>
> docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
$ dnf install -y which
$ which find
which: no find in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)
```

Every Linux distribution I've had experience with so far has had `find` pre-installed, so I'm not entirely sure what to do here.

A quick Google search yields results about how to *use* `find`, or why it can't be found when being used in a `bash` script, etc. But no matter the keywords I use, I can't seem to find anyone who has run into this before.

`dnf search find` shows no results, but perhaps it is under another name? Or is it something I will have to compile myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
# dnf whatprovides '*/bin/find'
findutils-1:4.6.0-24.fc31.x86_64 : The GNU versions of find utilities (find and xargs)
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/find

findutils-1:4.6.0-24.fc31.x86_64 : The GNU versions of find utilities (find and xargs)
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/find
```

```
# dnf install -y findutils
```